# Battle.net not downloading on Windows

Tags: windows, macbook, boot-camp

The help forums and Blizzard support have been no success.

Every time I click to install Battle.net, I get this pop-up saying "This app can't run on your PC", and I have no idea what could be causing the problem. I was able to download it just fine on macOS.

I have a MacBook pro 15" (Windows BootCamp), 8th gen intel cire i7 (2.8 GHz), Radeon Pro 560X 4096 MB, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB, 32 GB 2400 MHz DDR4 RAM.

I know I have a Mac and I'm trying to install it on Windows, but I've defiantly seen people do it before. I'm also running non-genuine Windows (free version without product key). Could this be the issue? I was able to install Steam and all my games on it just fine so I doubt it.

I have a link to a screenshot of the error here:

[image: Screenshot]

I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: The file is incomplete.  It’s 0 KB...

Answer (score 2):

> Every time I click to install Battle.net, I get this pop-up saying "This app can't run on your PC", and I have no idea what could be causing the problem.

*Battle.net-Setup.exe* is 0 KB.  Which is the reason it’s an incompatible incomplete executable.  Due to the way Firefox works, you have enough of the file for Windows to know it’s an executable, but you only have 412 KB of the file.  It’s incomplete.  You need to simply download the file properly.

> I'm also running non-genuine Windows (free version without product key). Could this be the issue?

Your installation of Windows has nothing to do with this particular problem.  There is no such thing as a “free” version of Windows.  Your installation is simply unlicensed.

> I was able to download it just fine on macOS.

Hopefully you are not attempting to launch the MacOS version of the file on Windows.

Comment: At long last I was able to get it to work, I created a new admin user and it worked. Don't know why that fixed it though.

Comment: Did you download the file again?  Was the location of the file on a network drive?

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you have a 32-bit version of Windows – which is [no longer supported](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/65159) by latest versions of Blizzard games (including Overwatch and WOW, but likely Battle.net in general too).

If that's the case, you have to reinstall Windows – even if the CPU is 64-bit, you cannot run 64-bit programs on a 32-bit OS kernel, nor can you convert an existing Windows system to another CPU architecture.

Comment: Battle.net launcher application is 32-bit, while Overwatch and World of Warcraft no longer have a 32-bit client, the application the author is attempting to run is 32-bit